# How to repeat a pandas data frame column x amount of times?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

If I have a Pandas Dataframe like this:

```
    A
 1  8
 2  9
 3  7
 4  2
```

How do I repeat it x number of times? For example, if I wanted to repeat it 3 times I would get something like this:

```
    A  B  C  D
 1  8  8  8  8
 2  9  9  9  9
 3  7  7  7  7
 4  2  2  2  2
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `concat`:

```
n = 3
pd.concat([df] * (n+1), axis=1, ignore_index=True)

   0  1  2  3
1  8  8  8  8
2  9  9  9  9
3  7  7  7  7
4  2  2  2  2
```

---

If you want the columns renamed, use `rename`:

```
(pd.concat([df] * (n+1), axis=1, ignore_index=True)
   .rename(lambda x: chr(ord('A')+x), axis=1))

   A  B  C  D
1  8  8  8  8
2  9  9  9  9
3  7  7  7  7
4  2  2  2  2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Numpy to repeat the values and reconstruct the dataframe.

```
n = 3
pd.DataFrame(np.tile(df.values, n + 1), columns = df.columns.tolist()+list('BCD'))

    A   B   C   D
0   8   8   8   8
1   9   9   9   9
2   7   7   7   7
3   2   2   2   2
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `concat` like @coldspeed [did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54563421/225020).

Or you can set them manually.

```
df['B'] = df.A
df['C'] = df.A
df['D'] = df.A
print(df)

   A  B  C  D
1  8  8  8  8
2  9  9  9  9
3  7  7  7  7
4  2  2  2  2
```